# FBe is not a function even though it is defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
<script>
         var userId = '1';
         var appId = 'MYAPPID';
         var appHost = 'https://localhost:44300/';
         // Api holder
         FBe = {};

         // FB JS SDK
         window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
             FBe = FB;
             FBe.init({
                 appId: appId,
                 status: true,
                 cookie: true,
                 xfbml: true,
                 frictionlessRequests: true
             }); 
         };

         (function (d, debug) {
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                 return;
             }
             js = d.createElement('script');
             js.id = id; 
             js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document, /*debug*/ false));

    </script>
    <script>
        // Test
        function fbTest() {
            FBe.api('/me', function (response) {
                alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
            });
        }


        fbTest();
    </script>
```

my code above gives me this:

`TypeError: FBe.api is not a function`

Why am i getting this error?

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `fbTest()` too early.  You have to wait until after `window.fbAsyncInit` has been called.  The FB API is not yet loaded.

Because you are loading the FB API asynchronously, you can't use it until after `window.fbAsyncInit` has been called.  Any use of the FB API upon page load should be called from `window.fbAsyncInit`.